# How to avoid Fragment Overlapping ? Android Default nav Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, overlap

MY FRAGMENTS ARE OVERLAPPING(SEE Screenshots)
how to Avoid this

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zGTs.png)

[how to Prevent this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFVTp.png)

Fragment Switch Code:

```
 else if (id == R.id.nav_improve) {

       Improve improve1 = new Improve();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, improve1).commit();
```

Content_Main (content_frame Layout)
...........................................................

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: can you give the detailed code?

Comment: Which Code do you need ?

Comment: ok ihave added the content_frame layout

Comment: the layout i posted has the id: content_frame

Comment: confused it says `R.id.content_frame` but then you show us a layout file?

Comment: what happens when you remove the `app:layout_behavior` ? Otherwise try using a `remove` and an `add` (instead of `replace`) in your transaction for a sanity check

Comment: thanks but is it not working